# Cordova Barcode Scanner installed but with error trigger the scanner

Tags: meteor, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

anyone have experience with this Cordova/Phonegap plugin?

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

I install the plugin with the following command: `meteor add cordova:phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@6.0.8`

Then `meteor run android-device`

I see from shell the plugin is download and installed. But when I click on button that trigger the following example code:

```js
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      },
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      },
      {
          preferFrontCamera : true, // iOS and Android
          showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
          showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
          torchOn: true, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
          saveHistory: true, // Android, save scan history (default false)
          prompt : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
          resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500
          formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
          orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
          disableAnimations : true, // iOS
          disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS and Android
      }
   );
```

I get error from shell stating:

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined"`

Please help give some hints or guidance on how to successfully use the plugin? Please help, thanks.